# Update table with two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a sql script that I want to update my table based on two conditions. If Fax is Null then I want it to be "N/A" which I have in my code already. The second condition I am not sure how to meet. The second condition is if there is a fax number to only display the last four digits of that fax.

My code so far is

```
Update Supp_copy
Set Fax = 'N/A'
Output
Inserted.SupplierID,
Inserted.Country,
DELETED.Fax as 'Fax before update',
INSERTED.Fax as 'Fax after update'
From Supp_copy 
Where Fax is NULL
```

My expected output would be

```
SupplierID  Country     Fax before update   Fax after update
----------  --------    -----------------   ----------------
2           USA         NULL                N/A
3           USA         (313) 555-3349      3349
16          USA         NULL                N/A
19          USA         (617) 555-3389      3389
25          Canada      NULL                N/A
29          Canada      (514) 555-2921      2921
```

How can I have two update or `Set` statements for one update? If I cannot, how can I achieve my end result?

Comment: Which database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Sql Server:

Using `right()` to get the last four characters of the fax number, within `coalesce()` to return `'N/A'` when fax is `null`.

```
Update Supp_copy
Set Fax = coalesce(right(fax,4),'N/A')
output
Inserted.SupplierID,
Inserted.Country,
DELETED.Fax as 'Fax before update',
INSERTED.Fax as 'Fax after update'
From Supp_copy
```

Comment: This works, just have to edit in the OUTPUT after the SET and I will mark this as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can just substring_index function to get last 4 digits and  coalesce function for null values.

```
Update Supp_copy
Set Fax =coalesce(substring_index(fax,'-',-1),'N/A')
```